# Zoom doesn't work in 5.0.0 like in version bevor

Tags: zooming, kineticjs

I habe a problem that the zoom function in the new 5.0.0 version doesn't zoom like bevor.

I have tested the new Version 5.0.0 with the follwing test:

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnwS5/117/).

I change the `.js`file to:

`http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.0.min.js`

and make the changes for the new scale function:

```
ui.stage.setScale(newscale); --> ui.stage.setScale({x:newscale,y:newscale});
```

The error is that the zoompoint in 5.0.0 is the left top corner and not the mousepoint liek bevor.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Currently you fiddle works correctly for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just change this if you are using kinetic.jsv5.0.0

You can also view all the changes made in [Kinetic.jsv5.0.0](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log)

```
ui.stage.setScale(newscale); --> ui.stage.setScale({x:newscale,y:newscale});
```

and

```
ui.stage.setOffset(ui.origin.x,ui.origin.y); --> ui.stage.setOffset({x: ui.origin.x, y: ui.origin.y});
```

or
Apply the following code:

```
var ui = {
    stage: null,
    scale: 1,
    zoomFactor: 1.1,
    origin: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    zoom: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var evt = event.originalEvent,
            mx = evt.clientX - ui.stage.getX(),
            my = evt.clientY - ui.stage.getY(),
            zoom = (ui.zoomFactor - (evt.wheelDelta < 0 ? 0.2 : 0)),
            newscale = ui.scale * zoom;

        ui.origin.x = mx / ui.scale + ui.origin.x - mx / newscale;
        ui.origin.y = my / ui.scale + ui.origin.y - my / newscale;

        ui.stage.setOffset({x: ui.origin.x, y: ui.origin.y});
        ui.stage.setScale({x: newscale, y: newscale});
        ui.stage.draw();

        ui.scale *= zoom;
    }
};

$(function() {
    var width = $(document).width() - 2,
        height = $(document).height() - 5;
    var stage = ui.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        draggable: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var box1 = ui.box = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        radius: 50,
        fill: '#00D200',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        draggable: true
    });

    var box2 = ui.box = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 150,
        y: 150,
        radius: 50,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        draggable: true
    });

    // add cursor styling
    box1.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    box1.on('mouseout', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    // add cursor styling
    box2.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    box2.on('mouseout', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    layer.add(box1);
    layer.add(box2);
    stage.add(layer);

    $(stage.content).on('mousewheel', ui.zoom);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bijaybhandari1989/6J8F5/4/

Comment: Thank you. I have problems with firefox browser, any one could put the code to firefox.